# NoReverseMatch at /config/list_enseignant/

Tags: django

I try to list instances of enseignant but I have the raised exception  **Reverse for 'dfi' with arguments '(14,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['config/ajoutdfi/$']** I don't know very well what to do if i delete all the instances of dfi I'll get list of enseignant.

**models.py**

```
class Enseignant(Personne):

    type_enseignant=models.CharField("Type d'enseignant",max_length=75, choices=(("misssionnaire", "Missionnaire"),("permanent", "Permanent"),("vacataire", "Vacataire") ),default='permanent' )  
    departement_enseignant=models.ForeignKey("Departement",max_length=75,  verbose_name="Département de tutelle", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    poste_enseignant=models.CharField("Poste de l'enseignant", max_length=75, choices=(("enseignant","Enseignant"), ('resp_niv', 'Responsable de Niveau'),
            ('chef_dpt', "Chef de département"), ("dfi", "DFI")),  )
    grade_enseignant=models.CharField("Grade de l'enseignant",max_length=75, choices=(('M./Mme','M./Mme'),('Ass','Assistant'), ('Cc','Chargé des Cours'),('Mc', 'Maître de conférences'),('Pr','Professeur')) )
    anciennete_grade=models.IntegerField('Ancienneté au grade', validators=[
        MinValueValidator(limit_value=0, message="L'ancienneté entrée est négative" ),
        MaxValueValidator(limit_value=50, message='Ancienneté supérieur à 50')
    ])
    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}   {1}".format(self.nom, self.prenom)

class DFI(Enseignant):
    faculte=models.OneToOneField(Faculte, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
class list_enseignant(ListView):
    model =Enseignant
    context_object_name = "liste_enseignant"
    template_name = "configuration/lister_enseignant.html"
```

**urls.py**

```
path(r'enseignant', views.enseignant, name="enseignant"),
path(r'list_enseignant/', views.list_enseignant.as_view(), name="lister_enseignant"),
path(r'updateenseignant/?P<pk>\d+/',views.update_enseignant.as_view(), name='update_enseignant'),
path(r'deleteenseignant/?P<pk>\d+/',views.delete_enseignant.as_view(), name='delete_enseignant'),

path(r'ajoutdfi/', views.dfi, name='dfi'),
path(r'list_dfi/', views.list_dfi.as_view(), name="lister_dfi"),
```

**traceback**

> C:\Program
>   Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in
>   inner
>
> ```
>             response = get_response(request)
>
>  ...
> ```
>
> ▶ Local vars C:\Program
>   Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in
>   _get_response
>
> ```
>                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
>  ...
> ```
>
> ▶ Local vars C:\Program
>   Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in
>   _get_response
>
> ```
>                 response = response.render()
>
>  ...
> ```
>
> ▶ Local vars C:\Program
>   Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py in render
>
> ```
>             self.content = self.rendered_content
>
>  ...
> ```
>
> ▶ Local vars C:\Program
>   Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py in
>   rendered_content
>
> ```
>         content = template.render(context, self._request)
>
>  ...
> ```
>
> ▶ Local vars C:\Program
>   Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py in
>   render
>
> ```
>             return self.template.render(context)
>
>  ...
> ```
>
> ▶ Local vars C:\Program
>   Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render
>
> ```
>                     return self._render(context)
>
>  ...
> ```
>
> ▶ Local vars C:\Program
>   Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in _render
>
> ```
>         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
>  ...
> ```
>
> ▶ Local vars C:\Program
>   Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render
>
> ```
>                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
>  ...
> ```
>
> ▶ Local vars C:\Program
>   Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in
>   render_annotated
>
> ```
>             return self.render(context)
>
>  ...
> ```
>
> ▶ Local vars C:\Program
>   Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py in
>   render
>
> ```
>             return compiled_parent._render(context)
>
>  ...
> ```
>
> ▶ Local vars C:\Program
>   Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in _render
>
> ```
>         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
>  ...
> ```
>
> ▶ Local vars C:\Program
>   Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render
>
> ```
>                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
>  ...
> ```
>
> ▶ Local vars C:\Program
>   Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in
>   render_annotated
>
> ```
>             return self.render(context)
>
>  ...
> ```
>
> ▶ Local vars C:\Program
>   Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py in
>   render
>
> ```
>                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
>
>  ...
> ```
>
> ▶ Local vars C:\Program
>   Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render
>
> ```
>                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
>  ...
> ```
>
> ▶ Local vars C:\Program
>   Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in
>   render_annotated
>
> ```
>             return self.render(context)
>
>  ...
> ```
>
> ▶ Local vars C:\Program
>   Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py in
>   render
>
> ```
>                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
>
>  ...
> ```
>
> ▶ Local vars C:\Program
>   Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in
>   render_annotated
>
> ```
>             return self.render(context)
>
>  ...
> ```
>
> ▶ Local vars C:\Program
>   Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py in
>   render
>
> ```
>             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
>
>  ...
> ```
>
> ▶ Local vars C:\Program
>   Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py in reverse
>
> ```
>     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
>
>  ...
> ```
>
> ▶ Local vars C:\Program
>   Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in
>   _reverse_with_prefix
>
> ```
>         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
>
>  ...
> ```
>
> ▶ Local vars

Comment: add your `urls.py`

Comment: Your `dfi` URL does not take any arguments, but you are passing "14". You will need to show the template where you are using `{% url "dfi" ... %}`.

Comment: Also, please remove that long traceback and on the error page click where it says "Switch to copy-and-paste view", then post the result here instead.